# When using a browser in my progress application the scroll bars never work correctly

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

When using a browser in my progress application the scroll bars never work correctly. It will show that I can only scroll down a little but then keeping going. Is this a bug in progress or is there something I can do to fix this problem?

```
define query browse-4 for customer.

DEFINE BROWSE BROWSE-4
QUERY BROWSE-4 NO-LOCK DISPLAY
  custNum name
/* ENABLE name */
WITH NO-ROW-MARKERS SEPARATORS SIZE 32 BY 6.46 FIT-LAST-COLUMN.
.

open query browse-4 preselect each customer no-lock.

enable browse-4.

wait-for window-close of current-window.
```

Comment: What is incorrect about the way that the scroll bars work?  What does "then keep going" mean?  If you are asking about potential bugs you should mention the version of Progress and the platform that you are running the code on.  Bugs tend to be specific to the environment.

Comment: OP is talking about position of the slider on the scrollbar being dependant on MAX-DATA-GUESS (which defaults to a really low number) rather than the number of records in the actual query.  Hence you can "keep going" even after the toggle reaches the bottom.

Comment: His comments suggest that he does not think that max-data-guess is related.

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust the MAX-DATA-GUESS property for the browse. You can get the value from NUM-RESULTS after the preselect query has been opened. Or you can set it to a suitable guesstimate without using preselect.

Keep in mind that using preselect causes every record to be read instead of just enough to fill the first browse window. That is potentially a lot of extra DB reads and network traffic just to get the scrollbars correct.

Comment: please tell if i am using the for each in open query what statements i will include for browse scrolling:                                                               open query browse-4 for each customer no-lock.

enable browse-4.

wait-for window-close of current-window.

Comment: sir i didn't understand your answer please tell clearly,or any other way.

Comment: What do you mean by "browse scrolling"?  Those words seem to mean something to you that they do not mean for the rest of us.

Answer (score 0):

You may be confusing the scrollbar on the containing frame with the scrolling of the browse.

Do you see two boxes outlining the browse?  If you add "with no-box" to your "enable" does the scrollbar that is bothering you go away?

If it does then the problem is that your containing frame (which is the default un-named frame because you have not specified a frame phrase with the ENABLE) is smaller than the browse viewport.  So you are seeing a scrollbar on the **FRAME**, not on the BROWSE, that is trying to tell you that you can scroll the frame up and down to see the complete viewport of the browse.  The browse may also scroll within that containing frame depending on how much data there is.

If you are running this code in a character (Unix) environment you should also be aware that many GUI features of the BROWSE are not available.  Especially anything related to appearance.  Like scrollbars.

Comment: sir ,please dont tell again and again my problem in different if  you have any solution please explain,please dont specify another model of my problem..as your answer

Comment: Nobody understands your problem.  Try clarifying it.

Comment: When using a browse in my progress application the scroll bars didn't work correctly.it is not scrolling to view data in browse fully

Answer (score 0):

This is a known "feature" of Openedge GUI, unfortunately.

The position of the slider on the right of the browse is not directly related to the number of records in the query, but to the "Max Data Guess" property of the browse.

You can set this value yourself in the property dialogue for the browse widget (it's just below the "query" editor, in v10 at least).

Just set it to a really big number (say 10,000) and the browse will behave as it should.

Comment: sir ,thank you for your answer ,you understand what exactly my problem is   ,but i am set value of MAX DATA GUESS value to 10,000 and above also ,but slider is not working.my output display records is maximum 500 only.

Comment: Then you only have 500 records in your table or temp-table. MAX-DATA-GUESS will act as a guide for the browser widget to size the scroll bars but will not limit the data in any way.

Answer (score 0):

the main problem for my question is mainly ,i am deleting temptable before completing the excecution,that is the main reason for the vertical-scrollbar is not working,after eleminating this temp-table deletion statements .automatically vertical-scrollbar is working.
for each ttdummy:
delete ttdummy.
end.